# how to get the option label instead of option value in magento admin panel grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, product-collection, grid

I am rewriting the magento admin panel grid for low stack products.
In that I have added the new column color in the grid.But this column shows the attribute value instead of showing label.
Below is my code which I added in grid.php

```
$this->addColumn('color', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('reports')->__('Product Color'),
    'sortable'  => false,
    'index'     => 'color',
    'type'      => 'options',
));
```

and below is the default collection in grid.php file.I didn't do anything in the collection.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_lowstock_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->filterByIsQtyProductTypes()
            ->joinInventoryItem('qty')
            ->useManageStockFilter($storeId)
            ->useNotifyStockQtyFilter($storeId)
            ->setOrder('qty', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
```

I am not sure if I have to do something in this collection.

Thanks,

Comment: you can get the label  using a renderer file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace your code in `Grid.php` with this

```
$this->addColumn('color', array(
    'header' =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Product Color'),
    'sortable' =>false,
    'index' =>'color',
    'type' => 'options',
    'renderer' => 'module_name/adminhtml_module_name_renderer_color'
));
```

Now create a file `Color.php` at path:

> Company/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Modulename/Renderer/Color.php

```
class Company_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Modulename_Renderer_Color extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
   public function render(Varien_Object $row)   
   {
        $value = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
        $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');
        $options = array();
        foreach( $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $option ) {
          $id = $option['value'];
           if ($id==$value) 
           {
            echo $option['label'];
           }

        }


   }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to add comment but due to new account, i haven't much reputation. Here is my solution to get value directly instead of getting from loop. Another thought you can add a break in loop once you got the value. $value = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex()); $attrValue = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product') ->getAttribute('color') ->getSource()->getOptionText($value); return $attrValue; I tried `echo $option['label'];` and i was getting double value. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to solve this problem.

I have written the seperate function in helper file as,

```
public function color()
        {
            $attribute_color = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');
    $allOptions_color = $attribute_color->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
    foreach ($allOptions_color as $color_instance) {
        $color[$color_instance['value']] = $color_instance['label'];
    }
    return $color;
       }
```

and I call this function in grid.php as

```
$this->addColumn('color', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Product Color'),
        'sortable'  =>false,
        'index'     =>'color',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'options'=> Mage::helper('reports')->color()
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add new column like below in your Grid.php file.

```
$whereyoucome = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer_address', 'whereyoucome');
            $options = $whereyoucome->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
            $whereyoucome = array();
            foreach ($options as $option){
                $whereyoucome[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
            }

    $this->addColumn('whereyoucome', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Where you come'),
            'index' => 'whereyoucome',
            'filter_index' => 'billing.whereyoucome',
            'type' => 'options',
            'options' => $whereyoucome
        ));
```