# Magento 2: How to filter product collection using product's final price

Tags: magento-2.1, price, product-collection, magento-2.1.1

How to filter product collection using product's final price. As I have special price and catalog price rule applied on the products.

**here is my code:-**

```
$searchedProducts = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();    
$searchedProducts = $searchedProducts->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('price', array(
                                array('gt' => $pricefrom, 'lt' => $priceto),
                            )
                        );
```

Above code filter the product using price.
But not give any result if i am using `final_price` in the product.

I want to filter products form there final price range.

Answer (score 5):

***`addAttributeToSelect`*** is not working because of `addAttributeToSelect`

> When a field is an eav Attribute

***But final_price field is not an eav attribute***.

At magento collection, it will  add via query.

> **Mistake,** if you have want filter the collection by final price then you should add Finals to your collection.So,you should add
>   `**addFinalPrice()**`

```
$searchedProducts = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();    
$searchedProducts = $searchedProducts->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFinalPrice();
```

Then filter the collection  via final_price,**you should use collection getSelect Query**

> ```
> $searchedProducts->getSelect()->where("price_index.final_price > ".$pricefrom)
>                   ->where("price_index.final_price < ".$priceto);
> ```

Comment: You are Great, Thanks for your solution, you save my time. I have used below:-
`$searchedProducts->getSelect()->where("price_index.final_price > ".$pricefrom)
                      ->where("price_index.final_price < ".$priceto);`

Comment: If possible Can you please advice on [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190640/magento-2-how-to-get-the-product-attribute-option-label-instead-of-option-value) also.

Comment: @PurushotamSharma https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @AmitBera can you please ans of this if possible https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/214624/magento-2-push-all-sale-product-to-bottom-of-the-product-list

Comment: perfect answer!!! +1 made my day :)

Answer (score 2):

Try `FieldToFilter` instead of `AttributeToFilter`

```
$searchedProducts = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();    
$searchedProducts = $searchedProducts->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addFieldToFilter('final_price', array(
                                array('gt' => $pricefrom, 'lt' => $priceto),
                            )
                        );
```

Comment: it show error: The \"final_price\" attribute name is invalid. Reset the name and try again.